# React Typescript on dynamic component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Using React with typescript I want to be able to create a dynamic component. Here is snapshot from code

```
const CustomTag = `${section.header_type}`;
<CustomTag className={styles.textimage__title}>{section?.header}</CustomTag>
```

on CustomTag markup in VSCode I get the following error

```
Type '{ children: string; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts
```

How do I define in this case for this component properly the types?

Comment: What type is `section.header_type`?

Comment: `section.header_type` is an enum for headers like h1, h2, h2 and is definable in backend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960411

Comment: Hi @lepsch the code alone works, just the type is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `CustomTag` type as being `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements`. It's going to be like the following code snippet.

```js
const CustomTag: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = `${section.header_type}`;
<CustomTag className={styles.textimage__title}>{section?.header}</CustomTag>
```

Just note that the `${section.header_type}` should be a valid HTML tag.

Comment: thanks for Feedback this approach hints the following `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof IntrinsicElements'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Try this instead: `const CustomTag = \`${section.header_type}\` as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;`